# Add new vocabulary to a Windows Store App

Tags: c#, windows, localization, windows-store-apps, multiple-languages

How can I use the multiple language toolkit for Windows Store apps. In the Internet there are many videos and texts, but on neither side is explained how I add new vocabulary. First I installed the multiple language toolkit and added it to the project. Then I added several languages.

For Windows Phone you just had to add to the list in the file AppRecources.resx new vocabulary.

Now I wonder how I add new words at Windows Store apps because there is unfortunately no list where I can enter all the words (like for Windows Phone), it must indeed be another way?

I think my question isn't the most difficult question, but I do not know how to solve it.
regards Christian

Comment: By 'Vocabulary' do you mean 'Alphabet' or 'Language'? Like, are you asking how to add, say, Chinese Simplified to your app? Or are you trying to add a word to be translated, such as if you already have Chinese added as a language and you want to translate "Start"?

Comment: Thank you, I know how to translate words, but how I can add new Words that I can translate to e.x Chinese.

Answer (score 0):

In your project, there should be a folder named the same as your primary language (i.e. "en-US", if your language is American English). In that folder there will be a ".resw" file, likely named `Resources.resw`. You can then add strings to it just like you would a .resx. When you Rebuild your application, the Multilingual App Toolkit will generate .xlf files inside of the `MultilingualResources` folder.

Comment: I can't find any *.resw file in my project.

Comment: Have you enabled the Multilingual App Toolkit and selected a language to add? If not, go to Tools -> Enable Multilingual App Toolkit, then right click your solution and there should be an option to add translation languages. Rebuild and they should appear.